# SWT Adding KeyListener to a Display

Tags: java, filter, swt, keylistener

I want to add a KeyListener to my existing window. I want to catch 3 KeyDown's. On the first KeyDown I want to put something in a Combo. On the second KeyDown I want to put something in another Combo. If both textbox are filled, I want the next KeyDown to simulate the OK Button.

But I have a problem with the error widget disposed. Because I dont know when to remove the filter correct. This only happend if I open the window again!

My Code:

```
_disp.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        if(!_disp.isDisposed()){
            _disp.removeFilter(SWT.KeyDown, this);
        }

        if (e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
            if (_cmbCCID.getText().isEmpty()) {
                _cmbCCID.setText(_lastFiveCCID[0]);
            } else if (_cmbDescription.getText().isEmpty()) {
                _cmbDescription.setText(_lastFiveComment[0]);
            } else if (!_cmbCCID.getText().isEmpty() && !_cmbDescription.getText().isEmpty()) {
                _btnOk.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this works only for the first click.. My window dont get all other KeyDowns

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the filter after the first key press. Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);

    display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener()
    {
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            if (i < 2)
                System.out.println("Press " + i);
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Press " + i);
                System.out.println("Remove");
                if (!display.isDisposed())
                    display.removeFilter(SWT.KeyDown, this);
            }

            i++;
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        while (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

It will remove the filter after the third key press event.

Comment: But if the user cancle the window after 1 key was pressed then I would get the same error or? Aren't there any other options to do this?

Comment: @user3589316 Then remove the filter when the user presses cancel... Or please elaborate what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @user3589316 If you're just tracking key presses on a specific widget, add a `Listener` rather than a filter.